# RegEx to match only certain product SKUs

Tags: regex

I have built a web crawler that extracts the SKU of products from the product name however I am struggling with finding the right RegEx to match only the SKU. Below is a list with products. From this entire wall of text I need to only extract the words in bold.

At line 8 and 24 there is no SKU available in the product name, so I would expect it to extract nothing.

I tried the following RegEx however, although close it's not perfect: ([A-Z]+[0-9]+([A-Za-z]+[0-9]+)?([A-Z]+)?)+([0-9]+)?([A-Z]+[0-9]?)

Any help is appreciated. :)

1. Memória DDR4 Crucial Ballistix Tactical Tracer RGB 8GB 2666MHz **BLT8G4D26BFT4K**
2. SSD Crucial MX500 1TB **CT1000MX500SSD1** Leitura 560MB/S Gravação 510MB/s SATA 3
3. SSD Crucial BX300 120GB **CT120BX300SSD1** Leitura 555MB/S Gravação 510MB/s SATA 3
4. Memória DDR4 Crucial Ballistix Sport LT Gray **BLS4G4D240FSB** 4GB 2400MHz
5. Memória DDR4 Crucial Ballistix Sport LT Red **BLS16G4D240FSE** 16GB 2400MHz
6. Memória DDR4 Crucial Ballistix Sport LT Grey **BLS8G4D240FSB** 8GB 2400MHz
7. Memória DDR4 Crucial Ballistix Sport LT White **BLS8G4D240FSC** 8GB 2400MHz
8. Kit Upgrade Placa Mãe Asus PRIME A320M-K DDR4 + Processador AMD Ryzen 5 2400G 3.6GHz + Memória DDR4 Cru
9. SSD Crucial MX500 500GB **CT500MX500SSD1** Leitura 560MB/S Gravação 510MB/s SATA 3
10. SSD Crucial MX500 250GB **CT250MX500SSD1** Leitura 560MB/S Gravação 510MB/s SATA 3
11. Memória DDR4 Crucial Ballistix Sport Lt White **BLS16G4D240FSC** 16GB 2400MHz
12. Memória DDR4 CRUCIAL BALLISTIX 16GB (2X8GB) 2400MHZ UDIMM **BLS2K8G4D240FSB**
13. Memória DDR4 Crucial Ballistix Sport LT Red **BLS2K8G4D240FSE** 16GB (2x8GB) 2400MHz
14. Memória DDR4 Crucial Ballistix Sport LT Red **BLS8G4D26BFSEK** 8GB 2666MHz
15. Memória DDR4 Crucial Ballistix Sport LT White **BLS8G4D240FSCK** 8GB 2400MHz
16. Memória DDR4 Crucial Ballistix Sport LT Red **BLS8G4D240FSEK** 8GB 2400MHz
17. Memória DDR4 Crucial **CT8G4DFS824A** SDP 8GB 2400MHz
18. Memória DDR4 Crucial Ballistix Tactical **BLT8G4D26AFTA** 8GB 2666MHz
19. Memória DDR4 Crucial Ballistix Sport LT Gray **BLS8G4D240FSBK** 8GB 2400MHz
20. Memória DDR4 Crucial Ballistix Sport **BLS8G4D240FSA** 8GB 2400MHz
21. Memória DDR4 Crucial Ballistix Sport LT Red **BLS8G4D240FSE** 8GB 2400MHz
22. Memória DDR4 Crucial Ballistix Sport LT White **BLS4G4D240FSC** 4GB 2400MHz
23. Memória DDR4 Crucial Ballistix Sport LT Red **BLS4G4D240FSE** 4GB 2400MHz
24. Kit Upgrade Placa Mãe Asus Prime X370-A DDR4 AM4 + PROCESSADOR AMD RYZEN 7 1700 3.0GHZ + MEMÓRIA DDR4 B
25. Memória DDR4 Crucial Ballistix Tactical Tracer RGB 8GB 2666MHz **BLT8G4D26BFT4K**

Comment: What is the SKU pattern specifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the examples you give I'm making the assumption that all SKUs must:

- consist of 12 or more uppercased letters and numbers
- contain at least a letter
- contain at least a number

Given these assumptions, you can use the follow regex to identify all the SKUs:

```
(?=\S*[A-Z])(?=\S*\d)[A-Z\d]{12,}
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/lOjGT5/1

Comment: Thank you, your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Can you mark this answer as accepted if you're able to validate it with more of your data sets? You can accept an answer by clicking on the grey check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that works for your examples...

```
[A-Z]{2}\w{10,13}
```

This will, however, match all-caps words of 12 characters or longer. Without knowing the rules of your codes it'll be hard to make it perfect.

You don't describe what your captures need to extract, are they just there for grouping?